# How to add multiple Rich Text Editors using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a `bootstrap` `plugin` to add rich text editors. If I'm working with one it is working well, but when I try to add multiple text editors it is showing only one text editor.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script src="editor.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".RTE").Editor();
         });
</script>
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="txtEditor" class="RTE"></div>
         <div id="Div1"  class="RTE"></div>
         <div id="Div2" class="RTE"></div>
```

**The Editor() is:**

```
$.fn.Editor = function( method ){

        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.Editor' );
        }    
    };
```

No matter how many `div` tags I add it is showing only one editor.

How can I add multiple (as many as I want) editors?

Comment: That editor plugin code doesn't tell us anything, it's just plugin boilerplate to help pass method strings into plugin function. Are you trying to write a plugin?

Comment: No, I'm just using it If you want I can post the whole `js` @charlietfl.

Comment: Better yet, just create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: [link]https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ This is where I got that from. Don't mind I have no clue how to add that in fiddle @charlietfl

Comment: suggest you just find another editor. That script could be modified for multiple instances but isn't set up for it now

Comment: Thats where I'm struggling, how can I do it for multiple instance

Comment: try this  https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/issues/52

Comment: tq, but this doesn't suit our way of coding  @charlietfl